# Salesforce Classic - Email Drafts

Tags: email, salesforce-classic

We are using Salesforce Classic (for a handful of reasons that I won't go into here). We are looking to enable Email To Case. I am going through a Sandbox to verify everything that is needed for our service center's requirements. One of the requirements is email approvals before sending. In searching, this lead me to the Salesforce Case Feed and Email Drafts.

In my Sandbox, I have enabled "Enable Email Drafts". I have also added the Email action to the Case page layout, so that this shows up in the Case Feed. When I look at the screenshot here (https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=case_interaction_sending_email.htm&type=5), they show where the Save link should be at for the draft. However, I do not see that anywhere on my page.

I am hoping that I am just missing something in my setups. Does anyone know why the Save link for the draft email is not showing up?

Here is a screenshot of the enabled checkbox in my Sandbox.

[image: Screenshot of Enabled Email Draft Checkbox]

Here is the image from the Salesforce Help Site linked above showing the Save Draft link below the Body.

[image: Salesforce Help Site Image]

Here is a screenshot of my Sandbox email. It does not have the Save link in the bottom.

[image: My Sandbox Email Form]

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Edit:
Per Request, here are other images. The first and second image below are showing 3 Email actions. The first Email action was already there, and that screenshot below is the same as the one above. The second Email action is one I created to see if there was something else that I was missing. The 3rd is linked to the Outgoing Email object, and does not show up on the View page.

The third and fourth images are of the case feed. You can see that the 3rd email action is not visible.

[image: Action Button Group]
[image: Email Actions on Page Edit]

[image: Email Action 1]

[image: Email Action 2]

Comment: Your settings look alright and I don't see any documentation step that you seem to miss. Can you confirm the email action you've on the layout is the right one? Do you see other email actions and if you do, please add them on the layout and see if it works.

Please share what you find as it would be helpful for others (including me!).

Thanks, Vishal

Comment: I have 3 Email actions to select. The first is the standard one. The second is one that I created after posting yesterday. The 3rd is linked to the Outgoing Email object, and does not show up on the Case Feed action area. I have added new screenshots to the initial post at the bottom.

Comment: The only button I use on my classic Case feed-based layout is the one with API name `Case.Email` and w/ drafts enabled, I see the button to save/discard draft